# Get Total Qty of product in the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns the following result

```
Service Date  Product1 Product2 
01/Jun/2015    1           3
02/Jun/2015    2           5
01/Aug/2015    2           5
02/Aug/2015    2           5
```

Instead of that i want to get total qty of each product by month so the out put should be like this.

```
Service Date  Product1 Product2 
Jun/2015       3           8
Aug/2015       4           10
```

Query

```
DECLARE @cols AS nvarchar(max),
        @query AS nvarchar(max)
SELECT
  @cols = STUFF((SELECT
    ',' + QUOTENAME(Product_Name)
  FROM dbo.Store INNER JOIN dbo.Servicelist ON dbo.Servicelist.Pro_ID = dbo.Store.Pro_ID 
  where CatID='2'
  GROUP BY Product_Name
  ORDER BY Product_Name
  FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE)
  .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
SET @query = 'SELECT Replace(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Service_Date, 126), '' '', ''/'') AS [Service Date],' + @cols + ' from ( select Service.Service_Date, Store.Product_Name, Servicelist.ProductQty FROM   dbo.Service INNER JOIN dbo.Servicelist ON dbo.Service.Service_ID = dbo.Servicelist.Service_ID INNER JOIN dbo.Store ON dbo.Servicelist.Pro_ID = dbo.Store.Pro_ID) x pivot ( SUM(ProductQty) for Product_Name in (' + @cols + ') ) p '
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `Service Date` ? Which version of `Sql Server` you are using ?

Comment: Which version of SQL SERVER ? 2008,2012 ?

Comment: How about label your table that you are showing, so that we know what table has the actual date and item counts that you want a sum of

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter you pivot query like this

In pivot grouping itself change the dates to `mmm/yyyy` format

```
SET @query ='SELECT Format(Service_Date,''MMM/yyyy'') AS [Service Date],'+ @cols+'
             FROM   (SELECT Service.Service_Date,
                           Store.Product_Name,
                           Servicelist.ProductQty
                    FROM   dbo.Service
                           INNER JOIN dbo.Servicelist
                                   ON dbo.Service.Service_ID = dbo.Servicelist.Service_ID
                           INNER JOIN dbo.Store
                                   ON dbo.Servicelist.Pro_ID = dbo.Store.Pro_ID) x
                   PIVOT ( Sum(ProductQty)
                         FOR Product_Name IN ('+ @cols +') ) p'
```

If you are using anything less than `Sql Server 2012` then replace

```
Format(Service_Date,'MMM/yyyy') AS [Service Date]
```

With

```
Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11), Service_Date, 106), 8), ' ', '/') AS [Service Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Service_Date` is of date type, try this:

```
select
    convert(char(3), Service_Date, 100) +'/'+ CONVERT(CHAR(4), Service_Date, 120),
    sum(Product1),
    sum(Product2)
from t
group by convert(char(3), Service_Date, 100) +'/'+ CONVERT(CHAR(4), Service_Date, 120);
```